# getContext of Null with canvas tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onload

I am running into an issue where I receive a

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null
```

for my canvas tag and I understand that it is caused by the javascript running before the the HTML document loads, but I thought window.onload would ensure that the javascript runs after the page loads. Any help as to where I am going wrong?

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bar Chart</title>
        <script src="Chart.min.js"></script>
        <script src="chartData.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="width: 50%">
        <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>

</body>
```

chartData.js

```
window.onload = function(){

    var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");


    var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(data, options);     

};

var data = {
    labels: ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "Number of Check-Ins",
            fillColor: "#81E6B3",
            strokeColor: "#177A9C",
            highlightFill: "#4E5C61",
            highlightStroke: "#A428C7",
            data: [20, 80, 30, 120, 12, 48, 12]

        }
    ]
};

var options = {
    scaleBeginAtZero : true,
    scaleShowGridLines : true,
    scaleGridLineColor : "#E69681",
    scaleGrideLineWidth : 1,
    barShowStroke : true,
    barStrokeWidth : 2,
    barValueSpacing : 5,
    barDataSetSpacing : 1
};
```

Comment: you don't seem to have an element with id of 'chart'

Comment: Wow @keune. Great catch. Don't know how I made that mistake. So simple.